# TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Tags: python, types

I don't understand what the problem is with the code, it is very simple so this is an easy one.

```
x = input("Give starting number: ")
y = input("Give ending number: ")

for i in range(x,y):
 print(i)
```

It gives me an error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python33/harj4.py", line 6, in <module>
    for i in range(x,y):
TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

As an example, if x is 3 and y is 14,  I want it to print

```
Give starting number: 4
Give ending number: 13
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
```

What is the problem?

Answer (score 34):

A simplest fix would be:

```
x = input("Give starting number: ")
y = input("Give ending number: ")

x = int(x)  # parse string into an integer
y = int(y)  # parse string into an integer

for i in range(x,y):
    print(i)
```

[`input`](http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/functions.html#input) returns you a string ([`raw_input`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input) in Python 2). `int` tries to parse it into an integer. This code will throw an exception if the string doesn't contain a valid integer string, so you'd probably want to refine it a bit using `try`/`except` statements.

Answer (score 11):

You are getting the error because range() only takes int values as parameters.

Try using int() to convert your inputs.

Answer (score 5):

```
x = int(input("Give starting number: "))
y = int(input("Give ending number: "))

for i in range(x, y):
    print(i)
```

This outputs:

[image: i have uploaded the output with the code]

Answer (score 3):

```
x = int(input("Give starting number: "))
y = int(input("Give ending number: "))
```

P.S. Add function `int()`

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you're running python3, in which `input(prompt)` returns a string.  Try this.

```
x=int(input('prompt'))
y=int(input('prompt'))
```

Comment: In python2, use int(raw_input('prompt'))

Answer (score 1):

You will have to put:

```
X = input("give starting number") 
X = int(X)
Y = input("give ending number") 
Y = int(Y)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to convert input x and y into int like below.

```
x=int(x)
y=int(y)
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can also use `eval(input('prompt'))`.

Comment: eval() will convert the expression to an evaluated version of the input.This is used to counter the backward non-compatiblity of python 3 against Python 2.

Comment: I used this in my program for factorial which was not working before(error given was : for i in range(1,n+1):
TypeError: must be str, not int)  and it worked:                                                                                                                            n = eval(input("Enter a number: "))
j=1
for i in range(1,n+1):
    j=j*i
    i=i+1
print(j)

Comment: This may work... But it creates an enormous security flaw, an attacker has quite literally free reign when you run eval like this without first properly checking the string...